# Link to another page doesn't work due to routing problem?

Tags: php, url-routing

When I click on a link on my index.php that goes to users.php page I get the same data as on index.php and it should be different. My link route to users.php is good and I think that the problem is in core controller (Core.php) I just can't seem to find the problem. Also controller name is UserController, and when I change the name of users.php to usercontroller.php and change a href also to usercontroller then it works just fine. Here is my code:

code structure:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- App
 |   |  
 |   +-- Controllers
 |       |
 |       +-- PageController.php
 |       +-- UserController.php  
 |   +-- Libraries
 |       |
 |       +-- Core.php
 |       +-- Controller.php
 |   +-- Views
 |       |
 |       +-- pages
 |           |
 |           +-- users.php
 |           +-- index.php
```

index.php:

```
<?php require '../App/Views/includes/header.php' ; ?>
<h1>Homepage!!!</h1>
<a href="users">Users</a>
<?php require '../App/Views/includes/footer.php' ; ?>
```

PageController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $this->view('pages/index');
    }
}
```

UserController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $this->view('pages/users');
    }
}
```

Controller.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

class Controller
{
    public function model($model)
    {
       require_once '../App/Models/' . $model . '.php';
       return new $model();
    }

    public function view($view, $data = [])
    {
       if (file_exists('../App/Views/' . $view . '.php')) {
        require_once '../App/Views/' . $view . '.php';
       } else {
         die("View does not exist!!!");
       }
    }
 }
```

Core.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

class Core
{
   protected $currentController = 'App\Controllers\PageController';
   protected $currentMethod = 'index';
   protected $params = [];

   public function __construct()
   {
       $url = $this->getUrl();
       if (file_exists('../App/Controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')) {
        $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
          if (isset($url[0])) {
            $this->currentController = '\App\Controllers\\' . ucwords($url[0]);
        }
          unset($url[0]);
        }
          $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

       if (isset($url[1])) {
         if (method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])) {
            $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
            unset($url[1]);
          }
        }
          $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
          call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
   }

public function getUrl()
{
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? According to the simplicity of that code, it should not be too hard to find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because now you searching for controller named `Users`. You should change your controller name and filename from `UserController` to `Users` or you can append this in your Core class:

```
   public function __construct()
   {
       $url = $this->getUrl();
       if (file_exists('../App/Controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). 'Controller.php')) {
        $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
          if (isset($url[0])) {
            $this->currentController = '\App\Controllers\\' . ucwords($url[0]).'Controller';
        ...
    }
```

And now if you have url for example /users you should name your controller as `UsersController`